# PHP mysql read function error (Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

This is database. php file: and I am getting fatal error on line 30($result = $stm->execute($data);)

The data and query there goes from the read function in the folder named user.class.php and I carry that function with it.

```
Class Database
{
    public static $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try{
            $string = DB_TYPE .": host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
            self::$con = new PDO($string,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$con)
        {
            return self::$con;
        }

        return $instance = new  self();
    }

    public function read($query, $data=array())
    {
        $stm= self::$con->prepare($query);
        $result = $stm->execute($data);

        if($result)
        {
            $data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
            if(is_array($data) && count($data) >0)
            {
                return $data;
            }
        }
        return false;

        
    }
```

user.class.php read function:

```
$data['url_adress'] = $this->get_random_string_max(60);
        //kayıtlı url_adress var mı
        $arr = false;
        $sql = "SELECT * from users where url_adress = :url_adress limit ";
        $arr['url_adress'] = $data['url_adress'];
        $check = $db->read($sql,$arr);

        if(is_array($check))
        {
            $data['url_adress'] = $this->get_random_string_max(60);
        }
```

So I have this error and  I dont know waht to do
error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\app\core\database.php:30 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\app\core\database.php(30):
> PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\app\models\user.class.php(54):
> Database->read('SELECT * from u...', Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\app\controllers\signup.php(12):
> User->signup(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\app\core\app.php(40):
> Signup->index('home') #4
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\public\index.php(15): App->__construct() #5
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ozimusic\app\core\database.php on
> line 30

Comment: Show us the `$sql` value.

Comment: You forgot to put a number after the `limit` keyword. It doesn't know how many rows to restrict it to. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx and  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html  for examples and specification.

Comment: You need to add limit 1 or any other number.

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much. I put limit 1 to password section of code but missed email thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SQL query is wrong as a `LIMIT` should have, at least, a row count.

**Solution 1**

Handle the limit and change the query to:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * from users where url_adress = :url_adress limit :row_count";
```

Don't forget to specify the expected limit:

```php
        $arr['row_count'] = 42;
```

**Solution 2**

Remove the limit if you want to retrieve all results:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * from users where url_adress = :url_adress";
```

**Documentation**

- [MySQLTUTORIAL - MySQL LIMIT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)
- [MySQL - SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: FYI, we don't usually asnwer off topic questions, but vote to close them instead

Comment: If I made a mistake I am so sorry , new araound here. But I dont get it how is it this question is off topic?

Comment: @OğuzhanÖztürk because it's basically just a typo, you simply forgot to put a number where you needed to.

Comment: Because it's unlikely helps anyone else and only adds a noise to the site, getting in the way for people searching of asking for answers.

Comment: Thank you guys for informations. I tried to find the problem but couldn't find it and thanks to you my problem was solved. If I have a problem again in the future, how can I get help without affecting the traffic of the site?

Comment: @OğuzhanÖztürk [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Just remenber that not every problem you encounter is suitable for Stack Overflow. This site is not a free help desk that is expected to solve any problem you got. Some are off topic.